# Laravel's blade template

Tags: laravel, web, mamp

I am new using laravel on blade templates.
So, everything I code the mamp server not showing the results of the code but just the code [image: figure]

Update:
 [image: route:]
Code:

```
 @extends('layouts.master')

@section('title', 'Laravel Shopping Cart')

@endsection

@section('content')
<h1>It works!!</h1>
@endsection
```

route:

```
     <?php
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('shop.index');
});
```

Comment: What is your file name?

Comment: how do you save the file name? as `.blade.php` ?

Comment: Please can you also show the code you're using to display the blade file i.e. controller method and route (or just route if you're not using a controller).

Comment: The file name is index.blade.php. I update the question. You can check

Comment: Route is wrong I think. Also, where is the controller?

Comment: I guess you mean the controller.php file?

Comment: No, you have to create your own `custom Controller, Route and View`. This is a part of `MVC`. I think you need to read the `documentation`, then you will get it.

Comment: @Rob Not true, routes can be closures too. https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing

Comment: Your route is set up for `/`, going to `http://localhost:90` should trigger that route and correctly display your `.blade` file.

Comment: @kerbholz I know that I was just explaining for the beginner.

Comment: question updated

Comment: You could even use a "View Route" to show that view: `Route::view('/', 'shop.index');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed: Problem was the route. There is nothing wrong with blade, just I was using wrong route.

Answer (score 2):

you don't want to directly access the blade files from your browser. You need to look into setting up a route, a controller, and returning the view from the controller.

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing is a good reference to help get started.

That you *can* directly reference the view from your browser points towards a mamp misconfiguration. You want to point the document root at the public folder within the project, not at the project itself.

Comment: That document root/public part is a nice addition.

Answer (score 1):

Blade only works if you use the view() method but currently you are just opening the file as a normal file.

What you need is a route & a controller:

**run this in your root folder**

```
php artisan generate:controller TestController
```

**Add this to routes file :**

```
Route:get('/test','TestController@index');
```

**add this to TestController in app/Http/Controllers**

```
public function index(){
  return view('shop.index');
}
```

Should work fine if you visit the correct route (`http://base_url/test`) and of course if your Http server is correctly configured.

Comment: fyi, controller not necessarily needed

Comment: What do you mean? Why it's not?

Comment: I mean you don't have to create/use a Controller to display a view, you can also use a closure in the routes file

Comment: you reminded me of the meme where a bird spins it's head fast so it can flies! i mean it did fly but that's not how it should be! i hope you get the point